# Pyinstaller - FileNotFound error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a python script and converted it into a .exe file by using:

```
Pyinstaller –-onefile RFOutputGraphs.py
```

It works, however one of the jobs in the scripts is failing, despite it working perfectly when run from Python.

My error is:

```
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] no such file or directory:
     'C:\\Users\\Nicholas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI30362\\currency_converter
     \\eurofxref-hist.zip'
```

I am guessing it is not recognising what is probably an unusual module (currencyconverter)

Is there a way of fixing this?

Thank you

Comment: Try using the `--add-binary` option. Something like `Pyinstaller --add-binary <path to zip>;currency_converter --onefile RFOutputGraphs.py`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried: Pyinstaller --add-binary <'C:\\Users\\Nicholas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI30362\\currency_converter\\eurofxref-hist.zip'>;currency_converter --onefile RFOutputGraphs.py  .... and it said it couldn't find the path specified. I looked and it isnt there. Hmmm

Comment: Don't actually include the '<' and '>'. And you need to find the actual location of that zip file. The path in the error message is where Pyinstaller is expecting to find it, but it isn't there. That's why you get the error. Adding that option will copy the zip file from its actual location (which you must specify in the option) to where Pyinstaller is expecting to find it.

Comment: Hey, got back to work this morning, it worked perfectly. Thank you. If you want to make your comment an answer I will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include the zip file in the .exe created by `Pyinstaller` using the `--add-binary` option as:

```
Pyinstaller --add-binary <path to zip>;currency_converter --onefile RFOutputGraphs.py
```

This copies the zip file from its location on your PC into the .exe file, and arranges for it to be extracted into the `currency_converter` folder (the location mentioned in the error message) when the .exe is run. Have a look at [Using Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html).