# Pyinstaller & Matplotlib. How to solve: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:..?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

with Pyinstaller I'm trying to make a .exe from a python file that uses tkinter and matplotlib.
However, every single time I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\tomma\AppData\Local\Temp\\_MEI15842\\matplotlib\\mpl-data\\matplotlibrc'
[9164] Failed to execute script interface
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller - FileNotFound error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156315/pyinstaller-filenotfound-error)

Answer (score 0):

New version of Matplotlib has issues with pyinstaller

Install the development version of `pyinstaller`:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```